# Elasticsearch Restoring large snapshot incomplete due to size

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-snapshot

I have a project where I need to restore a couple of snapshots one at a time in a read-only instance and reached a snapshot that is larger than the size I have on the machine and cannot increase size or add another node. I am filtering also by specific indices and can split that list and insert a batch first, process and delete them then insert the second batch. I cannot check the size of the indices before importing using [_status](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-snapshot-status-api.html#get-snapshot-status-api-example) as I am getting a timeout error so I have tried restoring the whole thing and wait until it fails. I got 108/215 indices restored now and would be able to list them and subtract from the second batch but I haven't found documentation on this scenario if the indices that have been successfully imported are complete.

Is there a way to find out if the imported indices up until the low storage issue occurred, are complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `_cat/indices` endpoint will show you what indices are in the cluster, which will cover anything restored

and the `_snapshot/_status` one will show you what's happening with restores if there are any running